# When will Blender Stackexchange get dark mode?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

In 2020 Stackoverflow finally got it's [dark mode release](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/31/building-dark-mode-on-stack-overflow/).

When will it be available on Blender Stackexchange?

Comment: Only the devs know that so I can't really answer your questions, but if I had to guess, based on the fact that our site uses a custom designed theme rather than the default one, and how relatively small our community is in terms of size by comparison,; I'd say it is far away

Comment: Should this question move to meta?

Comment: @MartyFouts isn't it already in Blender Stackexchange Meta?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear.  [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) is Stack Exchange's overall meta stack exchange.  It's where you typically ask about features that would be provided by the devs.

Comment: Ah ok please do that.

Comment: I can't, and I don't think the moderators can.  You'll probably have to register there and then ask the question.

Comment: Ok Then I will do that.